# Update validation on an automatically selected dropdown list value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

On an MVC form I have two dropdowns: Fruit and Color. The Fruit dropdown is populated by the controller. The Color dropdown is populated with Jquery based on the value chosen in the Fruit dropdown. There are only two options in the Fruit dropdown: Apple or Banana. If Apple is chosen, two choices appear in the Color dropdown: Red or Green. If Banana is chosen the color is automatically chosen to be Yellow.

Everything works fine except when I try to add validation. Upon submit, if there is no selected value in the either of the dropdowns a message appears next to each unselected dropdown. Then, when a value is selected the message goes away. This works fine when the value is selected manually, but when the value in the Color dropdown is automatically selected via code the message does not go away. The message only goes away when I click on the dropdown--like the value isn't actually selected until it is manually selected.

How can I get an automatically selected dropdown to behave like a manually selected dropdown?

**Model**

```
public class FruitVm
{
    public Fruit Fruit { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public List<Fruit> FruitList { get; set; }
    public List<Color> ColorList { get; set; }

}

public class Fruit
{
    [MustBeSelectedAttribute(ErrorMessage = "Please Select Fruit")]   
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public class Color
{
    [MustBeSelectedAttribute(ErrorMessage = "Please Select Color")]   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public class MustBeSelectedAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable // IClientValidatable for client side Validation
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null || (int)value == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    // Implement IClientValidatable for client side Validation
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        return new ModelClientValidationRule[] { new ModelClientValidationRule { ValidationType = "dropdown", ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage } };
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class FruitController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Fruit/

    FruitVm model = new FruitVm();

    public List<Fruit> GetFruits()
    {
        List<Fruit> FruitList = new List<Fruit>();

        FruitList.Add(new Fruit 
        { 
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Apple"
        });
        FruitList.Add(new Fruit 
        { 
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Banana"
        });

        return FruitList;
    }

    public List<Color> GetColors(int id)
    {
        List<Color> ColorList = new List<Color>();

        if (id == 1)
        {
            ColorList.Add(new Color
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Red"
            });
            ColorList.Add(new Color 
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Green"
            });

            return ColorList;
        }
        else if (id == 2)
        {
            ColorList.Add(new Color
            {
                Id = 3,
                Name = "Yellow"
            });

            return ColorList;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Colors(int id)
    {
        var colors = GetColors(id);

        return Json(new SelectList(colors, "Id", "Name"));
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        model.FruitList = GetFruits();

        model.ColorList = new List<Color>();

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FruitVm tmpModel)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

}
```

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("dropdown", function (options) {
        //  debugger;
        if (options.element.tagName.toUpperCase() == "SELECT" && options.element.type.toUpperCase() == "SELECT-ONE") {
            options.rules["required"] = true;
            if (options.message) {
                options.messages["required"] = options.message;
            }
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Fruit_Id").change(function () {
            var id = $(this).val();

            getColors(id);
        })
    })

    function getColors(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Colors", "Fruit")",
            data: { id: id },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            error: function () {
                alert("An error occurred");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var colors = "";
                var numberOfColors = data.length;

                if (numberOfColors > 1) {
                    colors += '<option value="">-- select color --</option>';
                }

                $.each(data, function (i, color) {
                    colors += '<option value="' + color.Value + '">' + color.Text + '</option>';
                })                

                $("#Color_Id").empty().append(colors);
            }
        })
    }

</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fruits Dropdowns</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(
                    x => x.Fruit.Id,
                    new SelectList(Model.FruitList, "Id", "Name"),
                    "-- select fruit --")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Fruit.Id)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(                    
                    x => x.Color.Id,
                    new SelectList(Model.ColorList, "Id", "Name"),
                    "-- select color --")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Color.Id)
            </li>
        </ol>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Can you strip down your code to the bare minimum to reproduce the problem? No one will want to read through all of that.

Comment: This is already stripped down to the bare minimum.

Comment: The problem actually comes from a much larger project. I reproduced the problem in a new project as simply as I could.

Comment: Would screen shots help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to force re-validation using:

```
$("form").validate();
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Nope. Doesn't seem to.

Comment: I've also tried simulating an Enter keypress, but that didn't work either.